# Average List from a List of Lists - Is there a more efficient way?

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x

I have a list of lists named 'run'. I am creating an average of those lists using this section of my code:

```
ave = [0 for t in range(s)]
for t in range(s):
    z = 0
    for i in range(l):
        z = z + run[i][t]
        #Converted values to a string for output purposes
        # Added \n to output
        ave[t]= ((str(z / l) + "\n"))
```

Much to my surprise, this code worked the first time that I wrote it. I'm now planning on working with much larger lists and many more values, and it's possible that performance issues will come into play. Is this method of writing an average inefficient in its use of computational resources, and how could I write code that was more efficient?

Comment: This looks asymptotically good. unless z overflows. (to avoid read http://www.johndcook.com/standard_deviation.html) but the builtin functions may be faster and clearer in practice.

Answer (score 5):

List comprehensions may be more efficient.

```
>>> run = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12, 13]]
>>> [sum(elem)/len(elem) for elem in zip(*run)]  
[5.666666666666667, 6.666666666666667, 7.666666666666667, 8.666666666666666]
```

Alternatively, you could try `map()`

```
>>> list(map(lambda x: sum(x)/len(x), zip(*run)))
[5.666666666666667, 6.666666666666667, 7.666666666666667, 8.666666666666666]
```

Comment: Whoops! Fixed. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can improve efficiency by having Python do more of the work for you with efficient built-in functions and list comprehensions:

```
averages = [sum(items) / len(run) for items in zip(*run)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
ave = [np.avg(col) for col in zip(*run)]
```

OR

```
ave = [sum(col)/len(col) for col in zip(*run)]
```

Comment: I don't see `itertools.zip` in the documentation, and this introduces a `numpy` dependency.

Comment: Thanks for the bugreport @user2357112. It is fixed. The `numpy` dependency is to harness the efficiency afforded by numpy, which is at least as fast as averaging without it

Comment: I'm still seeing `itertools.zip` here. What's that supposed to be? (While you're at it, this is a weird way to use numpy. Why wouldn't you use `numpy.average(run, 0)`?)

Comment: I think you want `itertools.izip`, instead of `itertools.zip`. Or just use  `zip`

Comment: `itertools.zip` is in 3.x what `itertools.izip` was in 2.x. Because of how it iterates over `run` and doesn't create a new list, it has better space complexity. And yes, there are likely much better ways to use numpy than I have - I am no numpy expert

Comment: duh, missed the python-3 tag on question :|

Comment: I'm pretty sure `itertools.izip` is just `zip` in Python 3. Check out the documentation for [`itertools`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) and [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip). Also, I don't think `numpy.avg` even exists.

Comment: @ersran9: actually, thanks for grilling me about it. Turns out that `zip` in python3 (standard lib) is python2's `itertools.izip`. I just checked the docs

Answer (score 0):

I entered this question looking for the following, which is dumb but as it does not use `zip` it does not ignore any value.
If you have a numerical list of lists with different lengths and want to find the average list

```py
import numpy as np

def my_mean(list_of_lists):
    maxlen = max([len(l) for l in list_of_lists])
    for i in range(len(list_of_lists)):
        while len(list_of_lists[i]) < maxlen:
            list_of_lists[i].append(np.nan)
    return np.nanmean(list_of_lists, axis=0)

aaa = [1, 2, 3]
bbb = [1, 2, 3, 5]
ccc = [4, 5, 6, 5, 10]
lofl = [aaa, bbb, ccc]
print(my_mean(lofl))
```

gives

```
[ 2.  3.  4.  5. 10.]
```

Comment: The part in which you are extending the list seems to be horribly inefficient for large differences in length of the lists.

Comment: I agree! any enhancement is welcome. That was enough for my personal use case